# How to generate an empty world in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to hack level.dat to make world generate new chunks with nothing but air blocks?

Or is there any tool to create such world?

Is it possible to give that world file to someone with vanilla Minecraft, and newly generated chunks will be without blocks too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Mystcraft](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/918541-125-mystcraft-09100/#entry11683085) is a mod that includes many different world generation features including a Void Age which is exactly what you describe. If you aren't partial against cheating then the notebook obtainable via the Creative Mode inventory will have all the different symbols available already learnt so that you can custom build whatever type of age you like.

The only other way is to use a map editing tool such as [MCEdit](https://github.com/mcedit/mcedit/downloads) to create a blank map, however this is limited to what you pre-generate as there's no way to make Minecraft generate blank chunks by default.

Comment: Mystcraft looks neat, I should try that!

Comment: @Zommuter: It's really cool, and Xcompwiz has some really cool plans for the future too.

Comment: But... my weekend... dammit :P Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [MCEdit](https://github.com/mcedit/mcedit/downloads) to create a completely blank world in vanilla Minecraft. Just create a world from scratch, and add some blank chunks. Your world will have nothing at all in it.

A couple of warnings, however:

- New chunks generated will be normal, since there is no way to make a "blank world" seed. You'll need to make as many chunks as you need in MCEdit.
- If you don't place *any* blocks at all, even if you edit the world in creative mode, you will not be able to add any new blocks to the world since there are no preexisting blocks to place new blocks on top of. You might want to add just one as a starting point.

Answer (score 3):

When creating a world, choose the Superflat world type, click
Customize, and remove all the layers.

Comment: I just tried this (in 1.4.7), and deleting all the layers appears to be equivalent to leaving them at default. However, entering the preset string `1x0`, or anything else specifying block 0 (other than `0` by itself) will produce an empty air world.

Comment: Since blocks can only be placed against other blocks you'll temporarily need a mod or external editor to add the first block to start your map, but after that this will give you a perfect empty world that will generate only empty new chunks even in vanilla.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy. When creating a new world, select superflat type, click customize, go to presets, and replace the text in the preset box with `2;0;1`. Then once you have created the world, use this command to place a block.

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:stone
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using [bukkit](http://bukkit.org), there's a [CleanroomGenerator](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/cleanroomgenerator/) plugin. You can then copy that world back to a vanilla one.

Comment: Is it possible to give that world file to someone with vanilla Minecraft, and newly generated chunks will be without blocks too? Can you give an example of such file?

Comment: I'm afraid not, only the chunks generated will be empty. But IIRC another bukkit plugin can pre-generate _many_ empty chunks. But in plain vanilla you will most likely not be able to achieve this. However, have a look at the Vanilla map [SkyBlock](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/600254-surv-skyblock/), it's surrounded by emptiness, but I don't know if that is eternal or just as far as one can see

Comment: @Zommuter: SkyBlock is empty for quite a way, but it's definitely not eternal, and it's all pregenerated to be empty.

Comment: @MatthewScharley thanks for checking, I half suspected this

Comment: @Zommuter: Don't thank me, I didn't check personally, but I've watched [a lets play](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLC2F778AABFB7556D&feature=plcp) where they built a bridge off to the mainland once they were done with the map.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MCEdit, and you don't need a rediculous amount of layers. You can use layercontrol to select the layers you want and delete them. Then, if you use the chunk control to create superflat chunks there and set the height to 1 and turn off grass, it will make a layer of bedrock right at the bottom. Then all you need to do is select and replace the bedrock with air!

Comment: Would this still work even if you travelled so far enough away from the spawn points that new chunks would generate?

Answer (score -1):

There is also a mod to disable terrain generation, it is in the Feed The Beast 1.2.5 pack. I think it is called "y u no make good map" or something like that.

Comment: Hey stevey, this answer would be much more useful with a link to that mod or pack.

Answer (score -1):

One great idea would be is for minecraft versions with customizable superflat worlds,

1. Go to create a world
2. Choose a gaming mode (I suggest you use Creative)
3. Go to more World options World Type >SuperFlat >Customize >Presets
4. Clear everything in the "Want to share your preset with someone" box.
5. Type in 95
6. Create World

And Ta-Da! Your world is made up of locked chests which slowly disappear.

if you can't wait do 12, but you may need a fast computer because it will make everything into sand and when you either place or break a block, everything falls in the void and has a big chance of making you lag.

Answer (score -2):

WARNING: THIS STRATEGY CREATES HUGE LAG AND YOU WILL NEED A STRONG COMPUTER. I TRIED IT, QUIT OUT, AND NOW MY WORLD WON'T LOAD. MINECRAFT 1.7.2.

1. Click "Create New World".
2. Change the gamemode to creative.
3. Select "More World Options".
4. Change World Type to Superflat.
5. Click "Customize".
6. Select "Use Preset".
7. Set the preset to Desert.
8. Select "Done" and delete all layers except for sand.
9. Select "Use Preset" again. Then, in the top box, take the only 8 you find and turn it into a 1.
10. Select "Done". It should now tell you the only layer is a top layer of 1-block-thick sand.
11. Select "Done" and then "Create New World". You should spawn into a world of sand and filled with cactus and slimes and dead bushes.
12. Begin flying.
13. Hover over the spot you want to place a block for your first island and set the spawn using /setworldspawn.
14. Prepare for intense lag and place whatever block you want the bottom of your island to be- NOT SAND OR GRAVEL.
15. After a few minutes of lag, you should have only your block in the world. 16. Build the first island or whatever of your world around it. TIP: If you move into different chunks, some sand may still be there. Simply place a sand or gravel, endure the lag, and there's another few chunks of air.

Answer (score -3):

Just create a superflat world and remove all the layers. (: