# How do you clear the blocks in the end to create something?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you clear a lot of blocks like in the end? I'm trying to clear all the blocks, but the /fill command won't do it.

Comment: Are you looking for a vanilla solution? Or are you willing to use mods or plugins?

Comment: Why won't the fill command do it? It is limited to 32768 blocks at a time, but the end is not too big, and if you want to clear everything, flying around and spamming this command with relative coordinates shouldn't take too long.

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to clear all blocks:**

This is not possible with `/fill`. One way to do this is to go to the superflat generator and in the box found when clicking 'presets', generate an empty world. See also: [How to generate an empty world in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/80279/how-to-generate-an-empty-world-in-minecraft)

**If you want to empty out a section:**

> /fill (X1) (Y1) (Z1) (X2) (Y2) (Z2) minecraft:air

Should do the trick. It's possible that you are filling too many blocks with air. If so, try one section at a time.